# Animated sliders with images and text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Does anyone know if any open source animate sliders exist, like the one on this Wordpress theme: http://vencorp.venmond.com/index-revolution.php

The only ones I can find are plugins for Wordpress websites, I was hoping there would be some standalone versions.

Thanks

Comment: Which "slider" do you mean? I can't figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for a carousel/cycle type thing?

Like this? http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/ or this http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/

Comment: Thanks for those. I was looking for something more like the example, so something which had animation for individual divs, rather than just a whole image sliding in.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, I wanted something very similar to the example I showed. Other well known sliders are too basic.

I found a solution though and I thought I'd answer in case it helps anyone else.

I opted for: http://www.themepunch.com/codecanyon/revolution/liveguide/02.Sample-Fullwidth.html

...which you can buy at http://codecanyon.net/item/slider-revolution-responsive-jquery-plugin/2580848

Seems really good so far.